# Use xcape-like Control_L=Escape only in Emacs evil insert-mode?

Tags: key-bindings, evil, keyboard-layout, escape

I like the idea of [xcape](https://github.com/alols/xcape) for exiting insert-mode by just quickly tapping Control_L, but I don't like how it leaves "unconsumed" escapes around in other modes, or in other programs/terminals, which mess up my flow.

(E.g. input is `xargs █oldcommand` and I'm about remove `oldcommand` with C-k, so I hit Control_L, then change my mind because I want to type "bash -c" first, but because of the escape that turns into `M-b ash -c` leaving me with `ash -c█xargs oldcommand`  instead of `xargs bash -c█ oldcommand`.)

Can Emacs itself handle lone modifier keypresses so I can have this only in evil insert-mode?

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround, inspired by the comment by Håkon Hægland in [Leave evil insert mode with control key](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/30190/leave-evil-insert-mode-with-control-key/30192#comment46485_30192)

First make a keycode for VoidSymbol with xmodmap (xcape can only work on keysyms that have assigned keycodes), then let xcape map Control_L to that instead of Escape:

```
xmodmap  -e 'keycode 255 = VoidSymbol'
xcape -t 175 -e 'Control_L=VoidSymbol'
```

Then just

```
(define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "<VoidSymbol>") 'evil-normal-state)
(define-key evil-visual-state-map (kbd "<VoidSymbol>") 'evil-normal-state)
```